# Using constructor injection with CDI in OpenLiberty

Tags: jax-rs, cdi, open-liberty

I'm building a small Java EE 8 application that should run on OpenLiberty.
It has a JAX-RS `ContainerResponseFilter` that looks like this:

```java
package my.package;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    private final MyService myService;

    @Inject
    public DiagnosticsFilter(final MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext request, final ContainerResponseContext response) {
        // Never mind this
    }
}
```

If I write the filter like this and start my app, the `myService` argument to the constructor is `null`.
However, if *field* is annoted with `@Inject` and the constructor is omitted, the field is being injected correctly.

The `MyService` class is annotated with `@Stateless`, and in `beans.xml` I have set `bean-discovery-mode="all"`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is this actually supposed to work? The [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.4.0.CR1/en-US/html/injection.html) suggests that it should, but I'm not sure it's in the CDI spec as well...

Comment: The `jaxrs` container is responsible for actually creating the filter, before delegating to `cdi` to perform CDI specific injection. That is why field injection works, but constructor injection does not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is there a way to have JAX-RS lookup its components in the CDI context, maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long story...And some people are working to solve the problem: JAX-RS injection != CDI injection
It shoud be solved in JAX-RS 2.2 ad CDI injection should be used in place of JAX-RS     injection and JAX-RS v3.0 will totally remove the JAX-RS injection
Read this on the subject:
https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2019/february/Jakarta_EE_9.php
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/issues/569
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/issues/639
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microprofile/gvj94XBhtvM